# Babel config in react.js

Tags: babeljs

i dont know what the main problem but i can't work with this error 
some one have a solution about this problem?
 ##

- Heading

  ### [bable problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BF2YC.jpg)

  [function didn't work when i use `= event =>`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVvSB.png)

  [.babelrc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRjyV.png)

  [package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5g589.png)

Comment: You're `.babelrc` image shows the `package.json` file, can you update it please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the look of your errors, there is just the plugin `@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties` missing from your .babelrc file.

You can find the plugin here with its docs: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties, and install it with the command:

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties
```